# Sending UDP in Camel/Netty and receiving extra bytes in NIO

Tags: java, netty, apache-camel

I have two applications, one that sends UDP messages using Camel with the Netty component, and one that receives UDP messages in Java NIO with DatagramChannel.

When receiving the data, I've noticed that there's an extra 29 bytes prepended to the front of my message. <s>Netty</s> Camel prints out the outgoing bytes and it looks fine, but when I do a packet.getData() as soon as the message comes in on the other side, it has extra stuff on the front (and it's always the same bytes).

Is Camel or Netty wrapping the packet before sending it?

[edit] Additional information:

-Camel is printing the log statement, not Netty
-the bytes prepended to the message change when the content of the message changes (only two bytes are changed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this question is pretty old now, but I hit exactly this problem and it took me a while to find the solution. So here it is...

Basically the problem boils down to confusion of what camel-netty will do when you're telling it to send something sufficiently low-level like a byte[] in a UDP packet. I expect that like me the OP assumed they were setting raw data, but camel-netty uses Java Object Serialization by default - resulting in those extra "random" bytes appearing before the expected data.

The solution is to change the encoder/decoder used by the endpoint(s) in question. There are various built-in alternatives, but you can subclass them if you need something more... weird. Either way, the process is:

1) Add the "encoder=#myEncoder" and "decoder=#myDecoder" options as appropriate on to the endpoint URIs. e.g.

```
String destinationUri = "netty:udp://localhost:4242"
        + "?sync=false&encoder=#myEncoder";
```

2) Add a mapping from "myEncoder" to an instance of your new Encoder class to a Camel Registry. Same for myDecoder. Then use that registry when constructing the CamelContext. e.g.

```
SimpleRegistry registry = new SimpleRegistry();
registry.put("myEncoder", new StringEncoder());
registry.put("myDecoder", new StringDecoder());
CamelContext camelContext = new CamelContext(registry);
```

Obviously the real trick is in finding or making an Encoder/Decoder that suits your needs. A blog post at [znetdevelopment](http://www.znetdevelopment.com/blogs/2009/04/21/netty-using-handlers/) really helped me, though it goes one step further and puts the custom Encoders in a custom Pipeline (I ignored that bit).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Good to finally find out what it was doing under the hood. We ended up going with pure NIO on both sides because we found the camel-netty implementation to be too slow for our needs.